# Determinant in a different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, change-of-basis

Let's say we are working in the basis $e_1'=(0,1)$, $e_2'=(1,0)$ (basically the standard basis but flipped). Then, the corresponding dual functions are $\lambda_1(x)=x_2$ and $\lambda_2(x)=x_1$.

We will use Leibniz's formula to find the determinant: For a nxn matrix A with columns $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$; $det(A)=det(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)=\Sigma_{\sigma\in{S_n}}sgn(\sigma)\lambda_1(v_{\sigma(1)}).\lambda_2(v_{\sigma(2)})...\lambda_n(v_{\sigma(n)})$.

Then, $det(id)=det((1,0),(0,1))=\lambda_1(1,0).\lambda_2(0,1) - \lambda_1(0,1).\lambda_2(1,0)=0-1.1=-1$

However, det(id) should be 1 and this is independent of the basis (as it is clear algebraically when we do $det(P.id.P^{-1})=det(id)=1$).

I am not seeing what I am missing and why I am getting -1 in the first case. In particular, how is the change of basis handled if we want to work on a non-standard basis directly?

Comment: Shouldn't the first term of the determinant formula be $\lambda_1(e_1')\lambda_2(e_2')$?

Comment: The identity remains the same in all basis so the first vector is still (1,0) and not (0,1)

Comment: What is this Leibniz formula about? What is the precise statement that allowed you to use this Leibniz formula? My definition of the determinant includes the statement $\mathrm{det}(\mathrm{id}) = 1$. What is your definition?

Comment: I am afraid you are very confused. The first basis vector in the (ordered) basis $e_1',e_2'$ is $e_1'$ (that is the vector $e_2$).

Comment: As @AndréCaldas suggests edit into your question a precise statement (in general) of this Leibniz formula when the basis is $v_1, v_2$.  Then apply it to the two cases in question.